# Memory card image

Tags: iso-image, disk-image

Nowadays we are capable of making CD disk images and we can mount them on a virtual drive, but can we do all these functions with our memory card? I mean in a phone can we make a image of a memory card, and whenever we want can we load it and surf the required data?

Comment: Questions on Super User are expected to generally relate to computer software or computer hardware in some way, within the scope defined in the [faq](http://superuser.com/faq). Questions about (smart)phones are considered off topic on Super User. Questions within this scope might be better fit on our Q&A websites [Android SE](http://android.stackexchange.com) or [Apple SE](http://apple.stackexchange.com) if you own an Android or Apple phone. Those are currently in open beta. Your contribution will help it stay alive. - Voting to close

Answer (score 0):

Sure we can make an image of a memory card, i.e. by using the [usb image tool](http://www.alexpage.de/usb-image-tool/). The problem is mounting the image as a memory card and not as a cd/dvd/bluray (like with demon toolz). I don't know any tool where we can specify what the virtual drive should be like. If you want to use it for backup reasons, there should be no drawback in mounting the memory card image as cd image, anyway.